# two dimensional array value swapping c++

Tags: c++, arrays, swap

```
using namespace std;

string piece;
string prompt;
int a,b;
int board[8][8];

const int  rook = 500;
const int knight = 300;
const int bishop = 305;
const int queen = 900;
const int king = 2000;
const int piyon = 100;

int startup[8][8] = {rook,knight,bishop,queen,king,bishop,knight,rook, piyon,piyon,piyon,piyon,piyon,piyon,piyon,piyon,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-piyon,-piyon,-piyon,-piyon,-piyon,-piyon,-piyon,-piyon,-rook,-knight,-bishop,-queen,-king,-bishop,-knight,-rook
};

void initial();
void updateboard();
void getinfo();
void move_piece();

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    initial();

    while(true) {
        getinfo();
        updateboard();
    }
    return 0;
}

void initial() {
    int a,b;

    for(a=0;a<8;a++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<8;b++){
            board[a][b] = startup[a][b];        
        }
    }
}

void updateboard() {

    system("cls");

    for(a=0;a<8;a++) {

        cout<<endl<<endl;

        for(b=0;b<8;b++) {

            if (board[a][b] == piyon) {
                piece = "P";
                goto label;                     
            }
            else if (board[a][b] == king ) {
                piece= "S";
                goto label;
            }
            else if(board[a][b] == bishop ) {
                piece = "F";
                goto label;
            }
            else if (board[a][b] ==knight) {
                piece = "A";
                goto label;
            }
            else if (board[a][b] ==rook) {
                piece = "R";
                goto label;
            }
            else if (board[a][b] ==queen) {
                piece = "V";
                goto label; 
            }
            else if(board[a][b] == 0)
            {
                piece = "0";
                goto label;
            }
            else if(board[a][b] == -king)
             {
                piece = "s";
                goto label;
            }
            else if(board[a][b] == -queen)
             {
                piece = "v";
                goto label;
            }
            else if(board[a][b] == -rook)
             {
                piece = "r";
                goto label;
            }
            else if(board[a][b] == -knight)
             {
                piece = "a";
                goto label;
            }
            else if(board[a][b] == -piyon)
             {
                piece = "p";
                goto label;
            }
            else if(board[a][b] == -bishop)
             {
                piece = "f";
                goto label;
            }
            else {
                piece = "0";
                goto label;
            }

        label:
            cout<<"  "<<piece<<"  ";
        }   
    }
}

   void move_piece () {

    int destinationrow;
    int destinationcol;
    int row;
    int col;

    cout<<"its your turn..."<<endl;
    scanf("%d %d",&row,&col);
    scanf("%d %d",&destinationrow,&destinationcol);

    int temp;
}

void getinfo (void) {

    cin>>prompt;

    if(soru.substr(0,4) == "exit") {
        return;
    }
    if (prompt.substr(0,3)=="new") {
        initial();
    }
    if(soru.substr(0,5)=="print") {
        updateboard();
    }
    if(soru.substr(0,5) == "move") {
        move_piece();
    }
}
```

here are my program codes, what i exactly want to do is swapping chess squares values so that i will be able to move pieces another squares.
though i did everything needed for a swap function it didnt work anyway.
piyon is in integer type and a chess piece that i want to make process on, moving another square. any help would be appreciated. regards..

Comment: `std::swap` already exists...

Comment: @Jarod42 but this does not look like C++ ;)

Comment: What makes you think it didn't work?

Comment: "it didnt work anyway" is not a useful problem description. It communicates exactly nothing useful about your problem.

Comment: BTW, rules in chess to move piece is more complicated than swapping random position.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i think its obvious what i just mentioned, it didnt work anyway means problem still goes on and couldnt find any practicable solution yet, without getting any error...

Comment: The code shown never defines board or the row column variables.   If board is a properly defined array of arrays, and the variables are in range, it should work.   However there is no move in Chess that swaps pieces, so this whole question seems bogus.

Comment: @GeneOlson no, i defined it as it should have been, wthin an infinite while loop, in my updateboard function that i wrote

Comment: If you are an auto mechanic, and someone called you and described their problem only that their car "didn't work anyway", or that their problem "still goes on", do you think you have any idea what needs to be done to fix their car? If not, why do you believe that anyone would have any idea what ***your*** problem is? The key to get help with a problem is to know how to ask an intelligent question, and describe the actual problem, instead of claiming that your program "didn't work anyway", and whatever problem you have "still goes on".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you dont have be indecent that much, i guess you should give "manner" a try, it will be quite useful for you to learn how to be a bit more kindsome to people that you dont know anything about....if you know nothing about the solution so there is no need to comment. how much hard could it be to say "i dont know" ?  just ask yourself where i was mistaken

Comment: Guiding you towards formulating an actual question so we can comprehend your problem is part of helping you. Don't forget that your goal while writing a question is to dump a stranger into code only you know so they can understand it *better* that you. Knowing how to ask is 80% of the way towards solving a problem.

Comment: News flash: nobody knows anything about any solution to your problem because nobody really knows exactly what your problem is. Your only description of the problem was that it "didn't work anyway", and that the problem "still goes on". That again, is like saying "my car doesn't move", and expect someone who fixes cars, and perhaps even knows a lot about cars, to know exactly why your car doesn't move. And speaking of manners, it is considered polite to read the Help Center before asking questions here, specifically how to post a [mcve]. Did you read it, and if not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

the function you have written swaps the fields for possible input values. Do you have some pieces on the board?

I set up a 8x8 board:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

initialized `destinationrow = 0` and `destinationcol = 0`, `row = 7` and `col = 7` and used your move_piece() function.
The output was:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

By the Way, why do you assign `temp = piyon`? it will never be used.

Comment: yes surely, all pieces on the board are set properly and ready to be used for any function.

Comment: but then I need some more information about e. g.: what is your input, what is your expected output and what the real output

Comment: i am right now posting all the codes look up carefully please :)

Comment: in the code above their is no "swapcode" like before you just declare `int temp`

Comment: what is `soru` in function getinfo()?

Comment: soru means prompt, my bad sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is... technical. I'd recommend a strong change in your layout. First of all, C++ is not meant to be used as a procedural language. That is, use classes. And use symbolism - "305" is an arbitrary number, not a bishop. If you don't want figures to be an actual class (with functionality), I'd start with:

```
enum Figure { pawn, rook, ... };
```

and then continue with a storage that represents a field:

```
enum Color { black, white };

struct Field{
    bool is_empty;
    Color player;
    Figure figure;
    Field(){ is_empty = true; }
    Field(const Color _player, const Figure _figure) : player(_player), figure(_figure) { is_empty = false; }
}
```

then build a class around that:

```
struct Coordinate{ size_t i, j; }

class Game {

//going with private first for you to get the structure
//in your code, you should start with public
private: 

    std::array< std::array< Field, 8>, 8> board; //use std::array instead of raw arrays

    void initialize_board();

public:

    Game();

    bool move_possible(const Coordinate from, const Coordinate to) const;

    void do_move(const Coordinate from, const Coordinate to);

    void print_board() const;
}
```

This would be where I'd start. You would probably add a lot more private methods, maybe some other features like a logger that notes all moves in chess typical manner and you might change the methods present. Maybe you need some way to get every possible move for a figure for displaying that on your UI. One thing that I'd do is to create methods like `move_possible_for_rook` in order to keep `move_possible` small, for example.

The important part that I wanted to show you is the symbolism. I used something that is a direct representation for everything instead of something that has to be interpreted. I did not use a 305 for a bishop, I used a class Figure. I did not use singular i and j to address a field but a structure Coordinate. I separated things into methods which give you an overview over the part of the code in which you are right now. This allows for the "what" to be in a small header file, giving you an overview over what can be called, while the "how" is in the source file, not being of relevance in your mind when you use it. Get the idea?

As for your question, with my style:

```
void Game::swap(const Coordinates coord_1, const Coordinates coord_2){
      std::swap(board[coord_1.i, coord_1.j], board[coord_2.i, coord_2.j]);
}
```

Simple as that. Take some tutorial on what the standard library contains and whenever you can use something from it instead of doing it on your own, do so.

Although in your context, swapping is somewhat unusual. Don't see any use for it aside from castling.

(Btw, some people might even argue that a figure should be a class that has responsibility over the move of a certain figure. Wouldn't go that far in your case, though. Would be useful if you plan to enable additional figures, as in fairy chess, but overkill in regular chess.)

edit: If you wanted figures to have values like 305 in order to manage the value of chess figures, with this "bishop has value 3" system - bad approach. Don't mix representation with function. In the style I proposed, you'd simply add a function `unsigned int value(const Figure figure);`.